# VB.NET Grab Text

Tags: html, vb.net

Alright so here is the HTML

```
    <li class="comment "
      data-author-viewing="False"
      data-id="FqTXOQTcyYaaGaT51z1St1pYFZW5ycutLsrLpoFIJow"
      data-score="0"
      data-author="pervychika666"> 

      <div class="comment-body"> 

  <div class="content-container"> 
    <div class="content"> 
      <div class="author "> 
        <a href="/user/pervychika666" title="pervychika666">pervychika666</a> 
      </div> 


        <div class="comment-text" dir="ltr"> 
          <p>Look at the female audience, they were all giggling and excited, a lot of women got excited with gay erotica, I admit I&#39;m one of them.</p> 

        </div> 
    </div> 


    <div class="metadata"> 
<span class="comment-actions comment-extra-actions"><a class="comment-action" data-action="flag">Flag</a><span class="comment-action-block"><span class="comment-metadata-separator">&bull;</span><a class="comment-action" data-action="block">Block User</a></span><span class="comment-action-unblock"><span class="comment-metadata-separator">&bull;</span><a class="comment-action" data-action="unblock">Unblock User</a></span><span class="comment-action-remove"><span class="comment-metadata-separator">&bull;</span><a class="comment-action" data-action="remove">Remove</a></span></span> 
      <span class="time"> 
        2 days ago
      </span> 

<span class="comment-actions"><span class="comment-action-vote-up"><a class="comment-action" data-action="vote-up">Like</a><span class="comment-metadata-separator">&bull;</span></span><span class="comment-action-vote-down"><a class="comment-action" data-action="vote-down">Dislike</a><span class="comment-metadata-separator">&bull;</span></span><a class="comment-action-reply comment-action" data-action="reply">Reply</a></span> 
    </div> 
  </div> 

      </div> 
  </li> 




  <li class="comment "
      data-author-viewing="False"
      data-id="FqTXOQTcyYagrOGji01HrGJn0tzIJeY4w1rxok5jrp0"
      data-score="0"
      data-author="mykellluvs"> 

      <div class="comment-body"> 

  <div class="content-container"> 
    <div class="content"> 
      <div class="author "> 
        <a href="/user/mykellluvs" title="mykellluvs">mykellluvs</a> 
      </div> 


        <div class="comment-text" dir="ltr"> 
          <p>I love their faces when they pull away from the kiss ;D</p> 

        </div> 
    </div>
```

Now where its like data-author="mykellluvs"> i want it to grab the name mykellluvs but do it for all of them cause there is more then one data-author=" thing on the page and paste it in a textbox

how can i do this?

Comment: try using [`HTMLAgilityPack`](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for this sort of thing...

Comment: I couldn't help but LOL at the content....anyway, you can do this with a WHILE loop - while your HTML string contains 'data-author="' get the data starting after the equals and going to the next " (or trim the "" if you prefer).  It's not a robust solution but if you are looking for quick and dirty it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the html or are you trying to parse html from some where else?
If you are generating this html yourself, you might want to pull this info from the datasource. If you are getting it from somewhere else then xpath might be your best bet
I use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing html with xpath like so

```
 // Targets a specific node
                HtmlNode someNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='posts']");
                // If there is no node with that class, someNode will be null
                if (someNode != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in someNode.Descendants())
                    {
                        if (item.Attributes["data-author"] != null)
                        {
                            myval = item.Attributes["data-author"];
                           // You can now check the value in myval to see if its what you want, 
                        }                            
                    }
              }
```

Sorry code is in c# but its easy enough to convert to vb.net. You can find more info on the documentation for HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zDM8VgBv look at my converted code
Hi, i converted it in vb.net and i got this error THE ERRORS

TYPE htmlnode is not defined
TYPE 'var' is not defined

Comment: and how can i make it paste it in a textbox

Comment: Hi vb.net doesn't support var so I guess you could use Dim item as HtmlNode see http://pastebin.com/tzH6qx7b

What exactly do you want to paste in the textbox?